# What to do with a database, retrieved by a SQLiteOpenHelper implementation, when finished using it?

Tags: android, sqlite

### Dear Fellow Android Developers!

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your answers. I see from many of them that it seems to be common (and accepted) practice to write your own `close()` method in your database adapter. Fair enough.

But how does that work with a `ContentProvider`? Usually when querying my database through my `ContentProvider` I simply issue something like:

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(...);
```

I don't see how I, with this methodology, can access the custom `close()` method in my custom `ContentProvider` implementation. Should I instead, from my `Activity`, do something like:

```
MyCustomProvider myProvider = (MyCustomProvider) getContentResolver();
```

and then:

```
myProvider.query(...);
myProvider.close();
```

And above all; is this at all necessary (as of point 2 below)?

**END EDIT**



To a certain degree I must say that I get the concept of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, what it is, how it's used and so. I even use it on a regular basis when I write my own `ContentProvider`'s.

The thing is that I'm not sure what to do with the `SQLiteDatabase` object, returned by the `myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()` (or the `myOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()` function for what matters) when I'm done with it.

According to Android `ContentProvider.onCreate()` documentation:

> You should defer nontrivial initialization (such as opening, upgrading, and scanning     databases) until the content provider is used (via `query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)`, `insert(Uri, ContentValues)`, etc).
>
> [...]
>
> If you do use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, make sure to avoid calling `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` from this method. (Instead, override `onOpen(SQLiteDatabase)` to initialize the database when it is first opened.)

The above gives me a hint where to initialize the database (the `query(...)`, `insert(...)`, etc functions), but it doesn't tell me anything on how to treat the created `SQLiteDatbase` object when I've finished using it.

1. *Should I save it as a member variable of my `ContentProvider` implementation (and treat it much like a "private singleton" for future use)?*
2. *Should I just leave it when exiting the `query(...)`, `insert(...)`, etc. functions and trust that the `SQLiteOpenHelper` will manage it for me in future calls?*
3. *[Insert your alternative point-of-view here]*

Being the confiding (or lazy) developer I've implemented my code according to the second alternative above. But I can't get rid of the creepy feeling that I'm neglecting something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with your database. If you just do an insert, delete or select where you get an business object back, then you can close the database right after using it. As far as I know it is designed that you simply close it and request a new one when ever you need it.

But be careful when you're working with a cursor then you have to keep the database open as long as the cursor is in use. Otherwise the application will crash when the cursor has to reload data.

Comment: Yes, I've also noticed the "crash-effect" you mention :-) Actually that behaviour is the very reason I started to wonder if I'm doing something wrong. Usually you send the `Cursor` object, returned by the `query(...)` method, right away to some adapter of some sort that will show the data in a list or so. Hence, you'll never know for sure when it's safe to close the database itself. Actually I would say it's not safe to close the database as long as such a list is shown. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I experienced when I worked with cursors, adapters and databases. If you think about the concept of a cursor this behavior makes sense, as it is the job of a cursor to get the data from the database row-wise and not to get the whole data at once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should close it, for example in onDestroy() of an activity that is using it.

So in my DBAdapter class I have:

```
/**
 * Close the database
 */
 public void close() {
     mDb.close();   //mDb was obtained using mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 }
```

And in my activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
     ...
     mDBAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
    // Open or create the database
    mDBAdapter.open();
 }    

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Close the database
    mDBAdapter.close();
    super.onDestroy();        
}
```

Not sure if this is suitable for your provider concept.

Comment: The idea is as beautiful as it is simple (and "simple is beautiful" as we all know :-) The question is if there is a difference between a custom adapter class and a custom content provider class from this perspective?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the example of use for that object in the [API](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) of Android, you can see the object is just used, but no close is necesary.

They implement the method close() though, but I havent seen they use it.

Comment: Great link, thanks a lot! However, they use a custom class (the `NotesDbAdapter`) that doesn't extend `ContentProvider`. How do I apply the `close()` methodology on my custom `ContentProvider` (respecting the aspects of thread safety etc.)? Do you think there is a difference between a custom database adapter and a content provider from this aspect? Also, please, see the edits I've made to my question for further elaboration on the problem.